# Delete a version of an app from Apple iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store

I am starting to put together an update for one of my apps in the Apple iOS App Store.  I have gone into the App Store Connect and created a new version for iOS.  I put the wrong version number in.  I do not see a way to delete this version.  I've googled and not seen anything.  How do I delete this version?  It has no build associated with it.

TIA.

Comment: You can't add another version. Simply change the version number for the new, unreleased version number you have created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a version on sale , you have to create a new version and associate it with the new build and then submit it for review , you can easily change this version build ( off course you'll submit a new update in future ) , but currently you can't delete it